# python ECDSA implementation miscalculation on big integers

Tags: python, algorithm, ecdsa

I'm trying to implement ECDSA using python as part of my homework, I have a function named `multiplication` which takes two arguments Point P and t calculates `B= tP`.I have implemented this algorith based on iterative double and add algorithm on [this wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve_point_multiplication) the problem is when p coordination is small(one or two digits), the algorithm works fine but when coordination is large (about 70 digits) the result is different than what it supposed to be. here is the part of my code which calculates `multiplication`:

```
def addition(self, p, q):
    if p.is_infinite:
        return q
    elif q.is_infinite:
        return p
    else :
        if (q.x - p.x) == 0:
            point = Point.Point(0, 0)
            point.is_infinite = True
            return point
        s = int(((q.y - p.y) * Utils.Utils.mode_inverse(q.x - p.x, self.prime)) % self.prime)
    xr = int((math.pow(s, 2) - p.x - q.x) % self.prime)
    yr = int(((s * (p.x - xr)) - p.y) % self.prime)
    r = Point.Point(xr, yr)
    return r

def double(self, p):
    if p.is_infinite:
        return p
    if p.y == 0:
        point = Point.Point(0, 0)
        point.is_infinite = True
        return point
    s = int((((3 * math.pow(p.x, 2)) + self.a) * Utils.Utils.mode_inverse(2 * p.y, self.prime)) % self.prime)
    xr = int((math.pow(s, 2) - p.x - p.x) % self.prime)
    yr = int(((s * (p.x - xr)) - p.y) % self.prime)
    r = Point.Point(xr, yr)
    return r

def multiplication(self, p, t):
    bin_t = bin(t)[2:]
    Q = Point.Point(p.x, p.y)
    Q.is_infinite = True
    for i, digit in enumerate(bin_t):
        Q = self.double(Q)
        if digit == '1':
            Q = self.addition(Q, p)
    return Q
```

Here is my Util class:

```
class Utils(object):
    @staticmethod
    def mode_inverse(a, m):
        return pow(a, m - 2, m)
```

Here is my Point class:

```
class Point(object):

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.is_infinite = False
```

I use `Curve P-224` parameters which are:

`p = 26959946667150639794667015087019630673557916260026308143510066298881`

`a = -3`

`b = 18958286285566608000408668544493926415504680968679321075787234672564`

`Gx = 19277929113566293071110308034699488026831934219452440156649784352033`

`Gy = 19926808758034470970197974370888749184205991990603949537637343198772`

according to calculator http://www.christelbach.com/eccalculator.aspx I should get this result for calculating 2G:

`Px = 11838696407187388799350957250141035264678915751356546206913969278886`

`Py = 2966624012289393637077209076615926844583158638456025172915528198331`

but what I actually get is:

`Px = 15364035107168693070617763393106849380516103015030577748254379737088`

`Py = 7033137909116168824469040716130881489351924269422358605872723100109`

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: No idea if this could be the issue, but you're using math.pow and a whole lot of ints, which make me twitch a little... python supports arbritary sized integers which make crypto algorithms theoretically easier, but math.pow produces a float which has finite precision... would suggest looking at doing everything as integers and see if that helps (e.g. replace math.pow(s.x,2) with s.x * s.x unless there's some subtle thing I'm missing here)

Comment: @Foon Wow! awesome! I was stuck on this problem for about 6 hours. can you please write your comment as an answer so I can choose it as the best answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was just a guess:

`math.pow` returns a floating point number (which has finite precision).  I'd suggest using e.g. `s.x * s.x` instead of `math.pow(s.x,2)` in case the issue is hitting precision issues with bigger numbers.